# Firebase React web app - Returning [Object Promise] instead of value, but in console it shows the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm building a react app using the Firebase Firestore database to create users, I want to get information like username and full name from the **users** collection, but instead of the value, it returns [Object Promise], I tried that in the console and it's working good. Here is my code:

```js
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
    .get()
    .then(function(doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            return doc.data().fullName;
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your code is contained inside another function. Then, you cannot return "synchronously" from a function after you used a Promise. The solution should be that your original function works asynchronously, too, and also returns a promise.

For example:

```
function getData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.email)
            .get()
            .then(function(doc) {
                if (doc.exists) {
                    resolve(doc.data().fullName); // <== Pay attention to this line, you resolve rather than return
                }
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting document:", error);
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

Then, calling your function asynchronously should be done such as:

```
getData().then((data) => {
    // Rest of your code
}).catch((error) => {
    // An error occured
});

//Rest of the code (after pulling data) is NOT here, it's inside the `then` part../
```

Comment: Can you make a little more elaborate? Maybe edit your question with what you tried to do (maybe some more code) and what it does... That would help us help you :-)